# Clip Seaborn Kdeplot within Bounds of PyPlot Background Image

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to graph NHL shots & their distribution (via Seaborn kdeplot) on a background image of an NHL rink provided by (x, y) coordinates in a Dataframe. The code I have generates the plot 99% of the way to where I want it to be, but I am not 100% sure how to clip the edges of the shot map such that it doesn't extend outside the bounds of the image loaded.

```
import os
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

random_events = ('SHOT', 'MISSED_SHOT', 'GOAL')
random_team = ('Preferred', 'Other')
events = list()

for i in range(30):
    event = dict()
    event['event_type'] = random.choice(random_events)
    event['team'] = random.choice(random_team)
    event['coords_x'] = round(random.uniform(-100, 100), 2)
    event['coords_y'] = round(random.uniform(-42.5, 42.5), 2)
    events.append(event)

df = pd.DataFrame(events)
pref_df = df.loc[df['team'] == 'Preferred']
other_df = df.loc[df['team'] == 'Other']

# Fix Coordinates
pref_df.loc[pref_df['coords_x'] < 0, ['coords_x', 'coords_y']] *= -1
other_df.loc[other_df['coords_x'] > 0, ['coords_x', 'coords_y']] *= -1

print(pref_df)
print(other_df)

MY_DPI = 96
IMG_WIDTH = 1024
IMG_HEIGHT = 440
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(IMG_WIDTH / MY_DPI, IMG_HEIGHT / MY_DPI), dpi=MY_DPI)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])

ax_extent = [-100, 100, -42.5, 42.5]
img = Image.open('Rink-Shotmap-Blank.png')
plt.imshow(img, extent=ax_extent)

# Draw the seaborn portion of the graph
sns.set_style("white")
sns.kdeplot(pref_df.coords_x, pref_df.coords_y, cmap='Reds', shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=0.6)
sns.kdeplot(other_df.coords_x, other_df.coords_y, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=0.6)

# Hide all axes & bounding boxes
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: Rink Shotmap]

Is there a way to clip the kdeplot onto the bounds of the [background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKyOv.jpg) (loaded via `ax.imshow`)? I have tried creating a `Path` object that is a rectangle the size of the extent, but with no luck.

If there are any other suggestions to the way this code is generated it would be greatly appreciated as these new visualization libraries are relatively new to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been nice to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can play along with the code you provided. But anyway, using the example code from [sns.kdeplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html?highlight=kdeplot#seaborn.kdeplot) and using the matplotlib demo: [Clipping images with patches](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_clip_path.html), it is fairly trivial to clip the `PathCollection` objects created by `kdeplot` using an arbitrary `Patch`

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]
virginica = iris.loc[iris.species == "virginica"]
ax = sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width, setosa.sepal_length,
                 cmap="Reds", shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
ax = sns.kdeplot(virginica.sepal_width, virginica.sepal_length,
                 cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False)

# create a Patch object, here in data coordinates to clip the KDE plots
p = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(xy=[2.5,5], width=2, height=3, transform=ax.transData, facecolor="xkcd:greenish", alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
for col in ax.collections:
    col.set_clip_path(p)

# simply for demonstration, show the patch on the axes (optional)    
ax.add_patch(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies - I thought the code I provided constituted an MCVE and was able to reproduce the output chart posted in the original post. Either way - this is great and definitely helped to solve the issue - thanks so much!